# HTML - How to view certain HTML elements (js,css) source document?

Tags: html

I have a HTML elements that goes by this `<select multiple="multiple" id="multi-select">`, now. How can I view where is the source of `id="multi-select"` comes from? (The asset.js/asset.css/style.css) I have tons of css/js loaded in the page, i just dont know where to find it.

Answer (score 1):

`multi-select` is the id of the `<select>` element and this helps while you are styling your HTML in the CSS, or use this id in the Javascript. This id plays vital role in the selector.

**Update:**

Use your browser's inspect element to find out the code which belongs to `multi-select` id.

Comment: This is quite useful, but I can't pin-point the certain page. Thanks by the way!